# Search Operators in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I wanted to display all of the data which have `gains` of greater than 1. But I seem to encounter problems on running the request on my postman with the url of :

```
http://localhost:3000/api/betHistory/winners
```

I get the result of:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `type`, `league_id`, `team_id`, `amount`, `gains`, `ratio`, `match_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `updatedAt` FROM `bets` AS `bets` WHERE `bets`.`gains` = false;
```

which should be `'gains' '>' '1'`

This is my **bet.js**

```
router.get('/winners', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = req.params.gains;
    const bets = await BetRepository.getWinnersBets(data > 1);
    res.json(bets);
  } catch (error) {
   res.status(400).send('No data found');
  }
});
```

This is my **BaseRepistory.js**

```
findAll(fields) {
const options = {};
if (!!fields && fields) {
  options.attributes = fields;
 }
return this.model.findAll(options);
}
```

And this is my **BetRepository.js**

```
const BaseRepository = require('../../../shared/repository/BaseRepository');
const Bet = require('../models/Bet');
const Op = require('sequelize').Op;

class BetRepository extends BaseRepository {
 constructor(model) {
  super(model);
}
getWinnersBets(gains, fields) {
  const options = {
   where: { gains }
 };
  if (!!fields && fields) {
   options.attributes = fields;
 }
 return this.model.findAll(options);
 }
}

module.exports = new BetRepository(Bet);
```

Any ideas on how to work with this? TYIA.

Comment: This has nothing to do with express.js. What library are you using to create the `Bet` model?

Comment: @Bergi yes, this was on my misunderstanding. I have solved this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by putting an operator on my **getWinnersBets**

```
getWinnersBets(fields) {
const options = {
  where: {
    gains: {
      [Op.gte]: 1
    }
  }
};
if (!!fields && fields) {
  options.attributes = fields;
 }
return this.model.findAll(options);
}
```

and removed the `> 1` line on my `const bets = await BetRepository.getWinnersBets(data > 1)`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `getWinnersBets(data > 1);`, you are not passing the expression `data > 1` to getWinnersBets, you are passing `getWinnersBets(true)` or `getWinnersBets(false)` to it, so in your query you are actually querying

```
'gains' '=' 'true'
```

and not

```
'gains' '>' '1'
```

I don't know the API of `model.findAll` so I can't give you a pointer on how to pass that expression to `findAll`

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and added the BaseRepository.js which is the location of my findAll() function.

Comment: You are using an `ORM` right? What library do you use for `this.model.findAll`?